# How do I change the size a Correlation Heatmap in Goole Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I need to get an image with readable text next to the axis.

I am using the following code:

```
def show_heatmap(data):
    plt.matshow(data.corr())
    plt.xticks(range(data.shape[1]), data.columns, fontsize=14, rotation=90)
    plt.gca().xaxis.tick_bottom()
    plt.yticks(range(data.shape[1]), data.columns, fontsize=14)

    cb = plt.colorbar()
    cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
    plt.title("Feature Correlation Heatmap", fontsize=14)
    plt.show()


show_heatmap(df2)
```

and the output looks at the moment like this:
[Correlation Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlfOL.png)

I already tried editing the code and added `figsize=(18, 35), dpi=80` behind the font size, but that just caused error messages and didn't help. I think I need to do something with the Matplotlib package here, as far as I have read, but I have no clue where and what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you insert the following code first. `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,35),dpi=80)`

Comment: If I change the Code to 
```def show_heatmap(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,50),dpi=80)
    plt.matshow(data.corr())
    plt.xticks(range(data.shape[1]), data.columns, fontsize=14, rotation=90)
    plt.gca().xaxis.tick_bottom()
    plt.yticks(range(data.shape[1]), data.columns, fontsize=14)

    cb = plt.colorbar()
    cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
    plt.title("Feature Correlation Heatmap", fontsize=14)
    plt.show()


show_heatmap(df2)```


It prints out the same figure as above but also says
`<Figure size 1440x4000 with 0 Axes>`

Comment: I added the code in my comment to your code and ran it. The graphs are displayed correctly, please refer to them as I expanded them in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IM7mGhdzujsPc4YjTbVFLbMK-IHaSIcf?usp=sharing). Is the `matplotlib` installed correctly because of this?

Comment: What is your execution environment?